# Is there any way that I can bypass Selenium Grid's auto-selection process?

Tags: selenium, amazon-web-services, selenium-grid

#### My Situation:

I have 60 dedicated selenium nodes that I use, in AWS.  My Selenium Grid and all my Selenium Nodes are in the AWS. (cuts down network requests)

#### My Problem:

I am experiencing an issue when executing my regression suite.  I run only 4 tests at a time due to our nightly servers only being able to handle so many tests going at it at once.  The problem that i've diagnosed is that when using `t1.micro` instances, the CPU tops off when launching only 1 test per 1 node.  I keep getting several timeouts.  Fine.  I can easily upgrade these to `m1.small` but it makes me think more about the way that the selenium grid selects it's nodes.  Per my understanding, this is a quick getup on how the hub handles it's nodes.
[image]

So if we only have 4 tests running at a time, it will select the first four nodes.  Once these nodes are finished running the tests, it will launch another test against the same instances.  **Is there any way that I can bypass this logic to just select a random available node rather than "the next one in queue"?**  I'm noticing that the `X` amount of nodes after the four nodes are NEVER being utilized.

#### Sidenote:

I have 60 nodes because this grid will have several different types of regression suites against it. Not only mine.

### Edit (July 25, 2015)

A pull request was created for this functionality: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/pull/832

Comment: May be not a perfect solution but I think this post(http://rationaleemotions.wordpress.com/2014/01/19/working-with-a-custom-capability-matcher-in-the-grid/) might be able to provide a workaround for you.

Answer (score 1):

This pull request should fix the issue

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/pull/832